# How to get user input and display a message if it is correct?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to code this for 2 days, but it is not working. It was working on the first day, but suddenly, it stopped.
This is my code-

```
    <html>

      <body>
      
          <input type="text"  id="input001"> 
          <button onlick="btn001()" id="submit"> Confirm </button>
          <br> <br>
          <p id="message001"></p>
          <script>
   function btn001() {
          var text001;
          var colors001 = input001.value;
            if (colors001 == "blue") {
            text001 = "The color is blue";
              document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = text001;
            }
          }
      </script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: do you get any console errors? can be found under f12 in most browsers, i assume `input001.value;` is empty/ undefined

Comment: I guess error is at "input001.value" . Shouldn't it be **document.getElementById("input001").value** ?

Comment: Typo in `<button onlick="btn001()" id="submit">` ---> `onclick`...

Comment: If still gives you errors - put the script in the `<head>` or before the button.

Comment: I've posted a working example in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

`input001.value` will not get the value.

Use `document.getElementById('input001').value` instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that in your function `input001` has no reference to the input tag whatsoever. Try to receive the value like this:

```js
var colors001 = document.getElementById("input001").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get the element first.
It should be like this:

```
var colors001 = document.getElementById("input001").value;
```

That should do it.

Also your button event is `onlick` instead of `onclick`.

Lastly, add a `.toLowerCase()` to the if statement used to check input to make it case insensitive.
Like this:

```html
 <html>

      <body>
      
          <input type="text"  id="input001"> 
          <button onlick="btn001()" id="submit"> Confirm </button>
          <br> <br>
          <p id="message001"></p>
          <script>
   function btn001() {
          var text001;
          var colors001 = input001.value;
            if (colors001.toLowerCase() == "blue") {
            text001 = "The color is blue";
              document.getElementById("message001").innerHTML = text001;
            }
          }
      </script>
      </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your button event. You wrote 'onlick'. But it must be 'onclick'.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the typo: `onclick` instead of `onlick`.
Added `onchange` to run button's `onclick` when [Enter] is pressed.
Made input and response more informative.
Used conditional (ternary) operator to determine response.

```js
function btn001() {
  var guess=document.getElementById("input001").value;
  document.getElementById("message001").innerText=
    guess=="blue"
      ?"Correct, the color is blue!"
      :"Sorry, the color is not '"+guess+"'.  Guess again!"
  ;
}
```

```html
<span>Guess a color: </span>
<input id="input001" onchange="btn001()"> 
<button onclick="btn001()">Guess</button>

<p id="message001">Results here</p>
```